# Validating is there any different menu item with capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I will try to improve the question.
How to validate if a different item is included in the menu: GAR?
I used it below and it still didn't work
page.all('select#tbm2').map(&:value).should == %w(Regras, GAR Regras, GAE Log Processamentos GAR/GAE)

```
<div id="tbm2" class="tb">
      <div id="TBH_tbm2" onclick="javascript:showMenu('tbm2','tbm2', true, true)" class="tbh">GAR</div>
      <div id="TBB_tbm2" class="tbb">
         <div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1370','Menu','','','.13.3','',''); " class="tbi tbiSel">
            <div>
               <div class="tbiIcon"><img src="r/std/static/pixel.gif" class="icon icon_config" draggable="false"></div>
            </div>
            <div>Regras GAR</div>
         </div>
         <div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1370','Menu','','','.13.4','',''); " class="tbi">
            <div>
               <div class="tbiIcon"><img src="r/std/static/collapse16.gif" class="icon" draggable="false"></div>
            </div>
            <div>Regras GAE</div>
         </div>
         <div onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1370','Menu','','','.13.6','',''); " class="tbi">
            <div>
               <div class="tbiIcon"><img src="r/std/icons/listini64.png" class="icon" draggable="false"></div>
            </div>
            <div>Log Processamentos GAR/GAE</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all('select#tbm2')` is going to find all `<select>` elements with an id of `tbm2`, of which there are none in your HTML. Also `.value` gets the `value` property of an element but you have all `div` elements which don't have a value.  If you wanted to use the approach you're trying for it would be something like

```
page.all('#tbm2 .tbi', count: 3).map(&:text).should == ['Regras GAR', 'Regras GAE', 'Log Processamentos GAR/GAE']
```

Another option would be to use a negative regex match, something like

```
page.find('#tbm2').should_not have_css('.tbi', text: /^(?!Regras GAR|Regras GAE|Log Processamentos GAR/GAE)/)
```

Another option would be to use the filter block that can be passed to most Capybara finder methods, like

```
page.should_not(have_css('#tbm2 .tbi') { |node| ['Regras GAR', 'Regras GAE', 'Log Processamentos GAR/GAE'].none?(node.text) })
```

Note: I'm using the `should` syntax because that's what you attempted in your question, but you really should be switching to RSpecs `expect` syntax nowadays